# Array stored in Mongo fails deep assert comparison to native javascript array with same length and values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, assert, mongoose

I have a field in mongo defined with the mongoose ORM like so:

```
state: {type: [Number], required: true }
```

If I take a peek at a sample document with the mongo console, state looks like

```
state: [ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

So far, so good. But strange enough for that same document the following assert fails:

```
assert.deepEqual state, [ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

Can't figure out if this is something I'm missing with object comparisons in JS or something to do with the way mongo is returning the state array.

Comment: `console.dir(state)`, `console.dir(Object.keys(state))` Look at the object, notice it's not an array

Comment: Ah. State has a bunch of extra properties that were hidden. So in this case, what's the best way to compare that the two arrays? I ended up using JSON.stringify to make the comparison. Better way?

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(state)` converts it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a bug where properties that should be non-enumerable are enumerated:

Eg, an array whose values are:

```
[ '0', '1']
```

has the following keys, according to `Object.keys()`:

```
[ '0', '1', '_atomics', 'validators', '_path', '_parent', '_schema' ]
```

Note Mongo now uses V8, which supports ES5, which has had the ability to **create non-enumerable properties via Object.defineProperty() for many, many years**.

As the other poster mentions:

```
var fixMongoArray = function(array) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(array)
}
```